# zsh bug on multiline commands: deleting messes up characters

Tags: zsh

if i type a multiline command, and run it, all works well.
When i press the UP arrow, and want to delete some characters, i see the deletion taking place. If I run the modified command though, i can see that the deletion was all wrong.

Usually it deletes/inserts characters shifted in one direction by one position.

Example:

```
$ sort file | uniq | grep -v 'some pattern' |less
```

I want to delete the word `file` and replace it with `other_file`. This is what I'll see

```
$ sort other_file | uniq | grep -v 'pattern' |less
```

This is what will actually run

```
$ sort fother_file | uniq | grep -v 'pattern' |less
```

Notice the name 'fother_file'. This is really annoying, and makes modifying history basically impossible. I end up copy-pasting the code in and out of zsh.

This is my ~/.zshrc file

```
HISTFILE=~/.zshhistfile
HISTSIZE=40000
SAVEHIST=1000
bindkey -v
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/shefuto/.zshrc'

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

if [ -f ~/.aliases ]; then
    . ~/.aliases
fi

export PS1="%{%F{yellow}%}%T]%{%F{green}%}%n%{%F{yellow}%} %~ %{$%f%} "

export WORKON_HOME=~/ve
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon tmp2

if [[ -e /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt ]]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt
fi
setopt PROMPT_SUBST ;
export RPROMPT='%{%F{red}%}$(__git_ps1 2>/dev/null)'

bindkey "^?" backward-delete-char

bindkey -e
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `%{...%}` shouldn't be necessary for `zsh` escape sequences like `%F`; `zsh` already knows that it doesn't advance the cursor. I'd also consider using `zsh`'s version control prompt status rather than trying to use `bash_completion`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PS1="...%{$%f%} "` tells `zsh` that `$` doesn't advance the cursor, so `zsh` doesn't have an accurate view of what the prompt length is. You also don't need `%{...%}` to surround `zsh`'s own escapes, since it knows they don't move the cursor. Try

```
PS1="%F{yellow}%T]%F{green}%n%F{yellow} %~ $%f "
```

`%{...%}` would be for enclosing an explicit sequence of escape characters like `\e[32m`, which is the ANSI CSI sequence for turning on green text. `zsh` uses its own terminal-independent sequence `%F{green}` for this.

```
PS1=$'%{\e[33m%}%T]%{\e[32m\%}%n%{\e[33m%} %~ $%{\e[0m} '
```

Comment: I think you're on to something - I'll check it out in more details later, but I think we've got a winner. Thanks! (I'll postpone marking your answer as correct a little, until I have time to check more thoroughly)